# Нужны ли знаки препинания: "Ломоносов как лингвист"?

Tags: пунктуация, как

**Ломоносов как лингвист.**

Как раставить знаки препинания?

Comment: Просмотрите вопросы и ответы с меткой "как". Там много полезной информации.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2):

**Ломоносов как лингвист**

Если это заглавие текста, то запятая не ставится: значение в качестве.

Другие примеры:

Ломоносов **как лингвист** известен не каждому (= в качестве).

Ломоносов, **как лингвист**, не мог не написать опровержение на эту статью (значение причины).

Я тебе **как лингвист** говорю. Разве ты сам не слышишь? [Елена Хаецкая. Синие стрекозы Вавилона/ Обретение Энкиду (1997)]

Потебня **как лингвист и философ** примыкает к Гумбольдту и его психологической языковой теории. [О. М. Фрейденберг. Поэтика сюжета и жанра (1935)]